# How can I check if my MacBook Pro is shut down without turning it back on?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power, shutdown

Sometimes I like to shut down my Macbook Pro (e.g. if I know I won't be using it for some time and I want to save battery).

Unfortuantely, I can't figure out any way to actually check that it's shut down when the lid is closed. There's no visible signal from the outside, and if I open up the lid, then due to (what I consider to be) a terrible design decision, it automatically turns back on. I then have to wait quite a few seconds before I can manually shut it back down again.

Is there a way I can either (a) see whether it's completely shut down without opening the lid, or (b) disable the automatic boot up upon opening the lid?

Answer (score 1):

Shut down before you close the lid.

Set the lid behavior so that it does not auto wake.

I set that behaviour when I want to clean the keyboard but you have to avoid the power button...

Comment: How do I set the lid behavior so that it does not auto wake? I don't see that option anywhere.

Comment: you could check out, after a quick search : https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/10/31/how-to-stop-the-new-macbook-pro-from-automatically-turning-on-when-the-lid-is-open/

Comment: That command gets it to no longer start up automatically upon opening the lid, but it still starts up if I press any key, so it's still hard to clean the keyboard.

Comment: Mine only starts on using the power key. Is yours asleep or fully shut down...

Comment: Fully shut down.